# Cannot watch browser window as it is being clicked by proctactor/jasmine tests

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

I am testing my AngularJS app with protractor, jasmine, selenium, webdriver-manager. I'm trying to have the browser kept on screen when the tests are through, be it only to see if the driver does the proper clicking, mousing and typing and whether my tests are true.

A statement like `browser.pause()` does not seem to work. It does suspend the browser, but apparently at the very beginning of the `describe` block. What could I do to actually have control over the browser (ie. watch it as it is being clicked, and pause exactly where I want)

My files follow (all tests pass):

**conf.js**

```
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:63342/bet/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  specs: ['my.spec.js'],
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    showColors: true,
    isVerbose : false
  }
};
```

**my.spec.js**

```
describe('my test suite', function () {

    describe('log file menu', function () {
        var logMenu = by.repeater('logfile in availableLogs');

        browser.get('index.html');

        it('show details', function () {
            element(by.css('[show="showDetail"]')).click().then(function () {
                expect($('.max-occupancy-detail').isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
            });
        });

        it('should verify number of log files', function () {
            element.all(logMenu).then(function(elements){
                expect(elements.length).toEqual(6);
            });
        });

        it('should verify the first option is selected', function () {
            var first = element.all(logMenu).first();
            expect(first.getAttribute('selected')).not.toBeNull();
        });

        it('should verify the second option is not selected', function () {
            var second = element.all(logMenu).get(1);
            expect(second.getAttribute('selected')).toBeNull();
        });

        it('should select the third option', function () {
            var third = element.all(logMenu).get(2);
            third.click().then(function () {
                expect(third.getAttribute('selected')).not.toBeNull();
            });
        });

        browser.pause();
    });

});
```

Comment: Do you want the browser to be brought in front and active during the test run, or you want the browser to stay opened after the tests are executed? Thanks.

Comment: Both. I sort of achieved that by putting `afterEach(function(){ browser.sleep(1000) })` in a describe block. However I expected some kind of configuration option to leave the browser open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the browser pause during a test, the browser.pause() needs to be put inside the the test which you would like to pause.

(The `it()` functions does not evaluate directly, instead they save the test functions you pass to be run later. That is why the pause happens directly in your example.)